# Should soapui questions from stackoverflow be migrated here?

Tags: discussion

I'm subscribed to the soapui tag on stackoverflow and they generally have a question or two day about soapui.  Since this is a common test automation tool, should we work to migrate the questions here? Do we have the community here to support it?

Comment: What are those questions like? Are they more or less coding questions? Or more about how to accurately apply the tool to being used. Obviously both are okay on SQA, but the coding questions -might- be better off there. For sure process questions should be migrated here.

Comment: I have experience with SoapUI and would probably be able to answer many questions, I just haven't really seen any here to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Do we have the community here to support it?
```

I do not know how to answer that.  However, an SQA search for "SoapUI" turns up several questions that were answered in a reasonable amount of time.